# How to make page not reload and not open php page after click on input with type submit?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have page in HTML CSS JS: https://handmade.company/seo/index.html
on this page i have form

```
<form class="webform" action="send.php" method="post">
            <input class="webinput" type="text" name="imja" placeholder="Ваше имя">
            <input class="webinput" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
            <input class="webinput" type="text" name="sajt" placeholder="Ваш сайт">
            <input class="webinput_btn" type="submit" value="Отправить запрос">
        </form>
```

with php file SEND.PHP

```
<?php
   $imja = $_POST['imja'];
   $phone = $_POST['phone'];
   $sajt = $_POST['sajt'];
   $wrong = 'при отправке сообщения возникли ошибки';
   $good = 'сообщение успешно отправлено';
   if (mail("office@handmade.company", "Заказ с сайта", "Ваше имя: ".$imja. " Ваш телефон: ".$phone. " 
   Ваш сайт: ".$sajt ,"From: office@handmade.company \r\n"))
     {     echo "<script>alert('$good');window.location.href='index.html'</script>;";
     } else {
         echo "<script>alert('$wrong');window.location.href='index.html'</script>";
      }?>
```

The problem is: when i click input with type="submit" button browser go to page https://handmade.company/seo/send.php and alert and after it it go back to index.html

I want: the page not reload and browser not redirect me to send.php page. I just want alert and nothing should change anymore

i tried to add function with preventDefault onclick on submit input BUT my php stopped working

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove send.php page
2. Change method = "post" to method = "get"
3. Do  `document.getElementsByClassName("webform")[0].onsubmit = function( e ) { e.preventDefault(); }`
4. Use JavaScript to get URL parameters which will be the values of the from
5. Then alert

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with Javascript or Jquery and Ajax. But if you want a simple way. You can try to add to your php file.

```
   header('Location: https://handmade.company/seo/index.html');
    exit;
```

replace https://handmade.company/seo/index.html for the url you want